# Restrict page to load while pagination using ajax in yii through CGridView

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I have been stuck for few days on ajax pagination..

in my `controller`, I have

```
$dataProviderRegSum = new CSqlDataProvider($rawData, array(
                'keyField' => 'FamilyId',
                'totalItemCount' => $count,
                'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>20)
));
```

here $rawdata is the result of query...

and in my `view` ,I have

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'id'=>'family-record-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderRegSum,
            'enableSorting' => true,
            //'cssFile' => $cssfile,
            'itemsCssClass'=>'tabchin',

            'columns'=>()
)
);
```

this is my grid view ,where I wanna display data with `pagination`..

my problem is that,while pagination ,total page is loading ...

but i want pagination with ajax in `yii`,without loading fullpage..

how to achieve it,please anybody help.....thanks for reading my question....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806877/yii-pagination-with-ajax

Comment: my problem is like this   http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25579-cant-use-ajax-pagination-with-cgirdview/

Comment: but dont have any idea which jquery file restrict or not ...and how to avoid conflict...

Comment: Have you opened console tab on your firebug to see any errors?

Comment: Yes ,I did that too ,but i didnt get any error at there...in this program ,I am loading lot of jquery files like google maps for autocomplete address field,and jquery-min,jquery-ui,modal files and js code written by me and js files from yii  into page ,,so i think any jquery conflict is occuring but dont know how to fix it

Comment: in clearly ,,,in my pagination cgridview is loading and page is also loading ,if i set yiigridview.js to false only page is loading...I wana stop page loading and allow only cgridview loading via ajax..

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'family-record-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderRegSum,
        'enableSorting' => true,
        //'cssFile' => $cssfile,
       'ajaxUpdate' => true,
       'itemsCssClass'=>'tabchin',

        'columns'=>()
));
```

Comment: oh...my goodness....I have tried `'ajaxUpdate'=>true,'ajaxUpdateError'=>'function to raise error'` but i didnt get any error...still full page is loading while pagination...

Comment: ok. But this will work for me. Please add Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');  in your view page.

Comment: this too doesnt effect ,cgridview is loading itself by ajax ,with this, page is also loading..how to stop page loading....

Comment: I have resolved this, first load `jquery.js` and next load `jquery.ba-bbq.js` in the page, that resolved the issue